# When should I use `protect-out` in Racket?

Tags: module, macros, racket, eval

Racket provides [`protect-out`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=protect-out#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._protect-out%29%29) to prevent module exports from being used with eval (or a deconstructed syntax object), unless the module has enough privileges (aka, has a [strong enough code inspector](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/stx-certs.html?q=code%20inspector#%28tech._code._inspector%29)). The docs also provide a good example for *what* it does:

```
> (module nest racket
    (provide num-eggs (protect-out num-chicks))
    (define num-eggs 2)
    (define num-chicks 3))
> (define weak-inspector (make-inspector (current-code-inspector)))
> (define (weak-eval x)
    (parameterize ([current-code-inspector weak-inspector])
      (define weak-ns (make-base-namespace))
      (namespace-attach-module (current-namespace)
                               ''nest
                               weak-ns)
      (parameterize ([current-namespace weak-ns])
        (namespace-require ''nest)
        (eval x))))
> (require 'nest)
> (list num-eggs num-chicks)
'(2 3)
> (weak-eval 'num-eggs)
2
> (weak-eval 'num-chicks)
?: access disallowed by code inspector to protected variable
  from module: 'nest
  at: num-chicks
```

That is, `eval` had a powerful enough code inspector (because it was called in the same scope that required the module originally) and therefore was able to get the export. However, `weak-eval` did not, because it got the same instance of the module, but with a weaker inspector to use for `eval`ing.

My question is, when should we use `protect-out`? Should it always be used (or at least whenever possible)? Or is there a specific work flow that `protect-out` is designed for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `protect-out` for *unsafe* exports, where unsafe means something that has the capability of violating the rules of the Racket language or virtual machine. In particular, it is often possible to crash the Racket VM by misusing unsafe features.

Examples of unsafe features:

- `unsafe-vector-set!` more or less lets you write to arbitrary memory locations, potentially violating the invariants of the GC, the invariants of Racket's value representations in memory, etc
- `unsafe-vector-ref` seems less immediately dangerous, but you could use it for example to extract the value of a free variable from a closure, even though the Racket language does not allow inspecting the implementation of a procedure
- most of `ffi/unsafe` is unsafe, obviously

Here's a less obvious example of an *unsafe* procedure:

```
#lang racket
(require ffi/unsafe ffi/unsafe/define)
(define-ffi-definer define-c #f)  ;; searches libc, etc
(define-c fopen (_fun _path (_bytes = #"a") -> _pointer))
(define-c fclose (_fun _pointer -> _void))
(define-c fwrite (_fun _bytes _size _size _pointer -> _size))
(define (append-to-file path buf)
  (define fp (fopen path))
  (unless fp (error "couldn't open file"))
  (fwrite buf (bytes-length buf) 1 fp)
  (fclose fp))
(provide append-to-file)
```

Consider the `append-to-file` procedure. It's defined using unsafe features (the FFI), but the FFI types `_path` and `_bytes` will reject bad Racket values, so it shouldn't be possible to crash Racket by using `append-to-file`. The `append-to-file` procedure is still unsafe (although perhaps not as catastrophically unsafe as `unsafe-vector-set!`) because it circumvents Racket's security guard mechanism. The procedure is unsafe in another way because `fopen` and `fwrite` can block, and Racket code is not supposed to block.

The unsafe operations in Racket's core libraries are provided with `protect-out`. If you use them to define your own unsafe operations, you should provide the derived unsafe operations using `protect-out` too. If you use unsafe features to define a *safe* feature, then you can provide that normally (that is, without `protect-out`), but think about it carefully first!

If you capture a privileged code inspector (either directly or indirectly via `#%variable-reference`), you should also protect that, because it can be used to dynamically gain access to unsafe features.

The goal is this: If a namespace contains only modules that have property protected their unsafe exports, then any additional code evaluated with a weaker code inspector should not be able to violate the invariants of the Racket VM (eg make it crash, circumvent security guard checks, etc).